# How to center a React component to the window/not be bound to <iFrame>

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe, centering

I have a React application that lives within an `<iFrame>`. In this application, we have various modals. These modals, when open, are centered according to the `<iFrame>`. How could I center the modal to be center window and not center of the `<iFrame>`.

Below is a barebones layout of the web application
[image: webApp layout]